# How make const variable available to other file

Tags: javascript, node-redis

I have a JavaScript / Node based project.  Within the server.js file (which starts the Node http server), I have a const based variable defined called redisClient.  I have another directory called controllers, with about 5 controller files (all *.js files).

How can I gain access to the redisClient const instance from my controller based files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use node very much... but I believe you can export anything you want from any file - and then require that file in other places and access what you exported on the export object. Depending on what you are doing, - you may want that redisClient to live somewhere else and be used in the server.js... not sure.

Read this: http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/

I hope that helps. : )  I use es6/es2015 imports and exports in most of my work.

Comment: Thank you for your response and that link, that page cleared this subject up for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could export the redis client that has been created in the server.js (either through module.exports or export const).

You could create another file that creates the redis client and import it into both server.js and the controllers.

You could pass the redis client into the controllers as a parameter.